# iOS - EKEvent with a location-based alarm

Tags: ios, calendar, location, eventkit, ekevent

I'm creating a 'just another task manager' app which heavily relies on the EventKit framework.

What I want to do is to add a geofencing alarm functionality. I've done some research and found the `EKAlarm` class which according to the docs is just what I need. As a container for those alarms I'm using the `EKEvent` instance (rather than `EKReminder`) - this is crucial because I want all my tasks to show app in the Calendar app.

The documentation says the following:

> While geofence-enabled alarms can be applied to events, they are more practical for reminders.

So it is clear that those geofence-enabled alarms **can** be used with events, but the thing is that I just can't make them work - the alarm doesn't get kicked off.

Here is some code I'm using for the alarm creation (it is in Swift yet I'm pretty comfortable with Objective-C):

```
let structuredLocation = EKStructuredLocation(title: marker.title)
structuredLocation.geoLocation = CLLocation(latitude: marker.position.latitude, longitude: marker.position.longitude)
structuredLocation.radius = kGeofenceRadius
<...>
let alarm = EKAlarm()
alarm.structuredLocation = structuredLocation
alarm.proximity = .Enter
event.addAlarm(alarm)
```

In iOS 8 if I open the Calendar app I can see the created event with **When I arrive** text in the **Alert** section - something you can't achieve using the standard interface. Under iOS 9 though it is different: the interface no longer says anything about the location, instead it shows **On day of event**.

[image: EKEvent with location-based EKAlarm on iOS8][image: EKEvent with location-based EKAlarm on iOS9]

Does anyone have an idea of how to make it work?

Thanks

Comment: Did you get a solution for this? Im trying to do the same thing and the alarm is not fired!